# how to extract capacity and digits from string in xslt template?

Tags: xslt

how to extract digit from string in xslt?

I have most title looks like:

1. Cumlaude S Ferulic Serum Bi Gel 30ml
2. Cumlaude Sunlaude Pediatrics Baby Spray Emulsion Spf50+ 200ml
3. Cumlaude Mucus Duplo Lubricating Gel 2x30ml

How Can I extrac only capacity?
example: 30ml

```
<xsl:element name="name">
                        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                    </xsl:element>
```

sample:

```
<xsl:element name="name">
                     Cumlaude S Ferulic Serum Bi Gel 30ml
                    </xsl:element>
```

Result:
30ml

Comment: What would be the **rules** for this extraction? And does your processor support XSLT 2.0?

Comment: If you're using XSLT 2.0+ then you would typically use regular expressions for this kind of task. But you need to define the task much more precisely.